# Which module to specify in Python's filterwarnings()?

Tags: python, warnings, suppress-warnings

Which module should I specify in the call to `warnings.filterwarnings()`? It does not seem to be the module where the `warn()` was issued, certainly not with imported third-party modules.

My concrete case:
I use some third party modules that output warnings generated by pandas. I want to suppress these pandas warnings while waiting for the package maintainers to fix the code. I only want the warnings to be suppressed for the code of the third party modules; I still want to get the warnings for my own code.

It is not straightforward how to specify the `module` argument in the call to `warnings.filterwarnings()`. It seems to work differently for different third party modules!

I avoid the context manager `warnings.catch_warnings()` because it is not thread-safe.

### Example 1: yfinance (v0.2.36)

```py
import yfinance as yf

df = yf.Ticker("AAPL").history()
```

emits warning

```
(...)/python3.11/site-packages/yfinance/utils.py:775: FutureWarning: The 'unit' keyword in TimedeltaIndex construction is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Use pd.to_timedelta instead.
  df.index += _pd.TimedeltaIndex(dst_error_hours, 'h')
```

I can suppress the warning by specifying `module="yfinance"`:

```py
import warnings
import yfinance as yf

warnings.filterwarnings(
    "ignore",
    message="The 'unit' keyword in TimedeltaIndex construction is deprecated",
    category=FutureWarning,
    module="yfinance",
)

df = yf.Ticker("AAPL").history()
```

gives no warning :-)

For info: the full call stack of the warning by simply doing `warnings.filterwarnings("error")`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "(...)/python3.11/site-packages/yfinance/utils.py", line 103, in wrapper
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "(...)/python3.11/site-packages/yfinance/base.py", line 313, in history
    quotes = utils.fix_Yahoo_dst_issue(quotes, params["interval"])
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "(...)/python3.11/site-packages/yfinance/utils.py", line 775, in fix_Yahoo_dst_issue
    df.index += _pd.TimedeltaIndex(dst_error_hours, 'h')
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "(...)/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/timedeltas.py", line 170, in __new__
    warnings.warn(
FutureWarning: The 'unit' keyword in TimedeltaIndex construction is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Use pd.to_timedelta instead.
```

### Example 2: pandas_market_calendars

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas_market_calendars as mcal

at_or_before = dt.datetime.now(tz=dt.timezone.utc)
nyse = mcal.get_calendar('NYSE')  # type: ignore
nyse_schedule = nyse.schedule(at_or_before - dt.timedelta(days=5), at_or_before)  # type: ignore
is_open = nyse.open_at_time(nyse_schedule, at_or_before)
```

emits warning

```
<stdin>:1: FutureWarning: Downcasting behavior in `replace` is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To retain the old behavior, explicitly call `result.infer_objects(copy=False)`. To opt-in to the future behavior, set `pd.set_option('future.no_silent_downcasting', True)
```

I don't find which module name I should give `filterwarnings()`. "pandas_market_calendars" doesn't do the trick:

```
import datetime as dt
import warnings
import pandas_market_calendars as mcal

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=FutureWarning, module="pandas_market_calendars")

at_or_before = dt.datetime.now(tz=dt.timezone.utc)
nyse = mcal.get_calendar('NYSE')
nyse_schedule = nyse.schedule(at_or_before - dt.timedelta(days=5), at_or_before)
is_open = nyse.open_at_time(nyse_schedule, at_or_before)
```

still emits warning

```
<stdin>:1: FutureWarning: Downcasting behavior in `replace` is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To retain the old behavior, explicitly call `result.infer_objects(copy=False)`. To opt-in to the future behavior, set `pd.set_option('future.no_silent_downcasting', True)
```

Even specifying `"pandas"` or `"pandas.core.internals.blocks"` (where the warning is issued) as module doesn't work.

```
import datetime as dt
import warnings
import pandas_market_calendars as mcal

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=FutureWarning, module="pandas")
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=FutureWarning, module="pandas.core")
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=FutureWarning, module="pandas.core.internals")
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=FutureWarning, module="pandas.core.internals.blocks")

at_or_before = dt.datetime.now(tz=dt.timezone.utc)
nyse = mcal.get_calendar('NYSE')
nyse_schedule = nyse.schedule(at_or_before - dt.timedelta(days=5), at_or_before)
is_open = nyse.open_at_time(nyse_schedule, at_or_before)
```

For info: the full call stack of the warning by simply doing `warnings.filterwarnings("error")`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "(...)/python3.11/site-packages/pandas_market_calendars/market_calendar.py", line 815, in open_at_time
    day = day.replace(self.open_close_map)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "(...)/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 8045, in replace
    return self.replace(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/janfr/.pyenv/versions/3.11.8/envs/jkx-3.11.8/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 8093, in replace
    new_data = self._mgr.replace_list(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "(...)/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/base.py", line 278, in replace_list
    bm = self.apply_with_block(
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "(...)/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 364, in apply
    applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "(...)/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py", line 1119, in replace_list
    result = blk._replace_coerce(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "(...)/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py", line 1223, in _replace_coerce
    return self.replace(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "(...)/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py", line 904, in replace
    warnings.warn(
FutureWarning: Downcasting behavior in `replace` is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To retain the old behavior, explicitly call `result.infer_objects(copy=False)`. To opt-in to the future behavior, set `pd.set_option('future.no_silent_downcasting', True)`
```

This puzzles me. What makes the situation for these two modules different?

More generally: what is exactly the "module" that we need to specify? [The documentation is not clear on this point.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#the-warnings-filter) It would be cool if we could specify any module on the call stack of the warning, but that does not seem the case.